# Is it possible show an image as grey color?

Tags: android, image

I have an image which is colorful:

[image]

But when I show it in an ImageView, I hope it to be grey:

[image]

Is it possible in android? Or do I have to create a grey image with some image editors?

Comment: Please help me fixing the English syntax errors in this question, I'm sure there are a lot. Sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't test this piece of code myself. But give it a try:

```
public Bitmap toGrayscale(Bitmap bmpOriginal)
{        
    int width, height;
    height = bmpOriginal.getHeight();
    width = bmpOriginal.getWidth();    

    Bitmap bmpGrayscale = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(bmpGrayscale);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
    cm.setSaturation(0);
    ColorMatrixColorFilter f = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm);
    paint.setColorFilter(f);
    c.drawBitmap(bmpOriginal, 0, 0, paint);
    return bmpGrayscale;
}
```